# How to display submitter name in Tumblr theme

Tags: tumblr

On Tumblr, one can enable a submission form, so that anyone can submit posts for approval.

I can't figure out, though, how to automatically display the submitter's name within my customized theme.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out `{PostAuthorName}` is used to accomplish this.

http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#group-posts